# Deserializing JSON List object

Tags: c#, json

I receive this JSON object from a web request:

```
"\"[{\\\"EventId\\\":25,\\\"StartDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-12T12:00:00\\\",\\\"EndDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-17T12:00:00\\\",\\\"Title\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"desc\\\",\\\"Teaser\\\":\\\"teaser\\\",\\\"PhoneNumber\\\":null,\\\"Email\\\":null,\\\"AddressOne\\\":null,\\\"AddressTwo\\\":null,\\\"City\\\":null,\\\"State\\\":null,\\\"ZipCode\\\":null,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"RegistrationUrl\\\":null,\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"c216cd34-6a3d-4f38-950b-ea3383a30a64\\\"},{\\\"EventId\\\":25,\\\"StartDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-13T12:00:00\\\",\\\"EndDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-18T12:00:00\\\",\\\"Title\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"desc\\\",\\\"Teaser\\\":\\\"teaser\\\",\\\"PhoneNumber\\\":null,\\\"Email\\\":null,\\\"AddressOne\\\":null,\\\"AddressTwo\\\":null,\\\"City\\\":null,\\\"State\\\":null,\\\"ZipCode\\\":null,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"RegistrationUrl\\\":null,\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"c216cd34-6a3d-4f38-950b-ea3383a30a64\\\"},{\\\"EventId\\\":25,\\\"StartDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-14T12:00:00\\\",\\\"EndDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-19T12:00:00\\\",\\\"Title\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"desc\\\",\\\"Teaser\\\":\\\"teaser\\\",\\\"PhoneNumber\\\":null,\\\"Email\\\":null,\\\"AddressOne\\\":null,\\\"AddressTwo\\\":null,\\\"City\\\":null,\\\"State\\\":null,\\\"ZipCode\\\":null,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"RegistrationUrl\\\":null,\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"c216cd34-6a3d-4f38-950b-ea3383a30a64\\\"},{\\\"EventId\\\":25,\\\"StartDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-15T12:00:00\\\",\\\"EndDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-20T12:00:00\\\",\\\"Title\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"desc\\\",\\\"Teaser\\\":\\\"teaser\\\",\\\"PhoneNumber\\\":null,\\\"Email\\\":null,\\\"AddressOne\\\":null,\\\"AddressTwo\\\":null,\\\"City\\\":null,\\\"State\\\":null,\\\"ZipCode\\\":null,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"RegistrationUrl\\\":null,\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"c216cd34-6a3d-4f38-950b-ea3383a30a64\\\"},{\\\"EventId\\\":25,\\\"StartDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-16T12:00:00\\\",\\\"EndDate\\\":\\\"2014-06-21T12:00:00\\\",\\\"Title\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"desc\\\",\\\"Teaser\\\":\\\"teaser\\\",\\\"PhoneNumber\\\":null,\\\"Email\\\":null,\\\"AddressOne\\\":null,\\\"AddressTwo\\\":null,\\\"City\\\":null,\\\"State\\\":null,\\\"ZipCode\\\":null,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"RegistrationUrl\\\":null,\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"c216cd34-6a3d-4f38-950b-ea3383a30a64\\\"}]\""
```

I have an object that matches this type called EventView and deserialize it into an object like so:

```
string result = "";
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

      result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JsonEventView ev = jss.Deserialize<JsonEventView>(result);



public class JsonEventView
{
    public List<EventView> results { get; set; }
}
```

However, I get an error every time I attempt to deserialize it.

```
Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'EventManagerService.JsonEventView'
```

Comment: It looks like your JSON is double-encoded, that is, you have a JSON string of a JSON object.

Comment: @univerio My return from the API is this: return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Active)); should I change that?

Comment: Perhaps add the code that makes the request to your answer.

Comment: @JeremyCook That is the code. the JSON object is stored as a string in result. Are you saying add the code that returns my JSON object?

Comment: Supposing that `Active` is the object that gets serialized then yes changing to `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Active);` should be the way to go EDIT: because Web API handles the serialization for you.

Comment: @JeremyCook Thank you. That was my problem right there. I didn't know that the serialization was handled for me. If you'd like to post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API handles the serialization for you. So *you* do not need to manually serialize the object to JSON.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Active);
```

Of course, Web API being able to return JSON hinges on [Content Negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) and your app being properly configured, such that there is a [formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) that can provide the output a consumer requests (JSON in this case).